# Gradle sync failed: For input string: "+"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I want to add Firebase SDK to my Android project.

I added

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
  }
}
```

to project level gradle file.

Then I added

```
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle asks for sync. And I get the following error:

```
12:35   Gradle sync failed: For input string: "+"
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

[image]

How can I fix that? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `+` sign from both dependencies. The `+` operator is not allowed as its own

Try using the specific version:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
```

Or

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.+
```

Which will fetch the most recent version of 11.0 release

Comment: 11.0.1 is a current version or what is it?

Comment: its a latest version

Comment: Even "11.0.+" doesn't work anymore!  It gives the same error which is annoying as it used to work before.  Google is removing functionality with its new releases....

Answer (score 3):

`+` is not recommended, better specify exact version.

Answer (score 2):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+` is not allowed. You can do following:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.+
```

Where `11.0.1` is the latest available version of the library included. And `11.0.+` means `include latest available version`.

Answer (score 2):

Please Remove the "+" from gradle file (Module Level) and add the lates version of that both library 
use short-cut-key  ctrl+altr+shift+s "project structure" click on dependencie

```
dependencies {
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules, just a `+` as version is not allowed.
You can write something like `1.+` meaning latest version that starts with `1.`.
If you always want the latest available version, use `latest.integration` as version like documented in above link.