# android studio gradle sync failed input string "<!"

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

when I open a project in android studio I have an error:

> Gradle sync failed. input string "<!".

I tried to clean and rebuild a thousand times but it doesn't help me.

Can you help me fix this?

**error**
[image]

and this is my build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ali.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
}
```

and this is my MainActivity file content:

```
package com.example.ali.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

these are the default contents and I didn't change any of them at all.

Comment: share your mainactivity.java and build.gradle

Comment: @AlirezaMortezaei Have a look at [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778247/gradle-sync-failed-for-input-string).

Comment: mainactivity.java is not modified and it has the default content

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati I've looked and done that but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove the "!" from where you written checkprobably it's hold into your build.gradle file.

your question is simpler to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778247/gradle-sync-failed-for-input-string)

You share nothing your code so right now i'll give a link and suggest you to Remove"!"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I searched for "!" in all gradle files of project and did not found any "!"

Comment: Share your mainActivity and Build.gradle now.

Comment: I shared those.